# How can I play DVD files using wmp.dll?

Tags: vb6, windows-media-player, wmp, dvd

I need help with my VB6 app. I have a form with a reference to `wmp.dll` (Windows Media Player 9 OCX). I can play many file extensions like MPG, MPEG, AVI, QT and others, but I want to play DVD files.  I'm using the following code:.

```
wmp.url = "D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_0.VOB"
```

This command works for all files, except from the DVD files.

I've also tried using:

```
commondialog1.showopen
wmp1.url=commondialog1.filename
wmp1.controls.play
```

This doesn't work.

The only function that works is:

```
wmp1.showplayer(url as string)
```

But this shows the media player object, and plays the file.  I want to see the movie in my form not in the mediaplayer.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ramses1974: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I made a few edits to try and make your post a little more readable.  I don't think I changed any meaning.  If I did, please feel free to change it back.  Hopefully someone who knows more about this will be able to help you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the DVD like this:

```
dvd://E:\
```

Where `E:\` is the DVD drive on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

See [Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758070(VS.85).aspx). Particulary it may be worth to pay attantion to [DVD Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562798(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally do it in Delphi, supposed the DVD is the drive D:

```
wmp1.URL := 'wmpdvd://D';
```

and here is how you explore the DVD playlist URL

```
procedure TForm1.ExploreDVD;
var
  i, j : Integer;
  cd: IWMPCdrom;
  pl: IWMPPlaylist;
begin
  for i := 0 to wmp1.cdromCollection.Count - 1 do
  begin
    cd := wmp1.cdromCollection.Item(i);
    pl := cd.Playlist;

    WriteLn( cd.driveSpecifier );
    WriteLn( pl.Name );
    for j := 0 to pl.count-1 do
      WriteLn(pl.Item[j].sourceURL);
  end;
end;
```

Hope this helps other people looking for the answer.